# Apache Tomcat Server 8.0.32 and a blue color default Favicon

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have deployed abc.war file on Apache Tomcat 8.0.32. Everything works fine except the favicon.ico. Even on index.html I have defined like :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

It shows icon like this :

[image]

Not sure from where this icon is coming ?

EDIT:

I also tried to see via developer tools of chrome , but didn't get the info of this blue icon.As checked all images retrieved from the network.
[image]

Comment: Open Developer Console in your browser, switch to the network tab, and reload the page. Watch the requests, and inspect the one for `favicon.ico`.

Comment: I did that already but that didn't show any clue, I can add that information to this question as well.

Comment: There should be a request like `http://your.server.com/yourApp/path/favicon.ico` - find it and paste the URL here.

Comment: @Agreed, I checked and didn't find such request :-(

Comment: Flush browser cache. It must have come from somewhere.